# Why readonly and volatile modifiers are mutually exclusive?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, readonly, volatile

I have a reference-type variable that is `readonly`, because the reference never change, only its properties. When I tried to add the `volatile` modifier to it the compiled warned me that it wouldn't let both modifiers apply to the same variable. But I think I need it to be volatile because I don't want to have caching problems when reading its properties. Am I missing anything? Or is the compiler wrong?

**Update** As Martin stated in one of the comments below: Both readonly and volatile modifiers apply only to the reference, and not to the object's properties, in the case of reference-type objects. That is what I was missing, so the compiler is right.

```
class C
{
    readonly volatile string s;  // error CS0678: 'C.s': a field cannot be both volatile and readonly
}
```

Comment: The compiler is [potentially wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39004125/1149773) (although possibly not for your particular scenario).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Neither the `readonly` nor `volatile` modifiers are penetrative.  They apply to the reference itself, not the object's properties.

The `readonly` keyword asserts—and enforces—that a *variable* cannot change after initialization.  The variable is the small chunk of memory where the reference is stored.

The `volatile` keyword tells the compiler that the contents of a variable might be changed by multiple threads.  This prevents the compiler from using optimizations (such as reading the variable's value into a register and using that value over several instructions) that might cause problems with concurrent access.  Again, this only affects the small chunk of memory where the reference is stored.

Applied this way, you can see that they are indeed mutually exclusive.  If something is readonly (can only be written to once, at initialization or construction), then it can't also be volatile (can be written to at any time by multiple threads).

---

As for your concern about caching issues, IIRC, there are pretty strict rules about when the compiler can cache the result of a property call.  Keep in mind that it **is** a method call, and it's a pretty heavy optimization (from the compiler's stand-point) to cache its value and skip calling it again.  I don't think it's something you need to concern yourself with overly much.

Comment: The properties may be uncacheable (I wouldn't know), but the backing fields definitely are. The fields should be marked volatile.

Comment: This answer addresses the OP's question correctly, but it contains a misleading statement: "The volatile keyword tells the compiler that the contents of a variable might be changed by multiple threads." That is only partially correct; the volatile keyword also tells the compiler that the contents of a variable might be changed *or read* by multiple threads concurrently, even if the change is only ever performed once. I've posed a similar question here that covers this issue: [C# language flaw: volatile and readonly should not be mutually exclusive](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39004125/1149773).

Comment: I don't think my statement is misleading. Perhaps it would have been more precise to say that it tells the compiler that a variable's value may be changed by other threads while a thread is reading it, but I think *that* phrasing is more misleading without further explanation, as it might imply that `volatile` is all that's necessary to provide thread synchronization. I think my wording explains the concept clearly, and the next sentence provides enough detail for a basic understanding. Your issue is an interesting examination of .NET's initialization behavior,but it doesn't detract from this.

Answer (score 1):

A readonly field can only be written when the object is first constructed. Therefore there won't be any caching issue on the CPU because the field is immutable and can't possibly change.

Comment: I understand your logic, but I disagree. An object can be readonly and still changes through its properties, because its properties aren't readonly. The readonly property in this case only prevents from assigning the variable to another object. At least is that what I understood from what I learned.

Comment: @Vernict: The readonly and volatile modifiers only protect the reference (or the value in case of atomic values like bool, int), not the content of the object! That's a completly different matter.

Answer (score 0):

While the reference itself might be thread-safe, its properties might not.  Think about what would happen if two threads tried to simultaneously iterate through a List contained *within* your reference object.

Comment: But that's something neither read-only nor volatile are intended to protect against. That's something you need to solve with synchronization anyways.

Comment: @Charlie, you are saying that even if the object is volatile, it doesn't guarantee that its properties will be volatile?

Comment: @Martin C, very true.

@Vernicht, As I understand, yes.  You'll need to guarantee that your fields and properties are thread-safe.